# Pulling data from MySQL via PHP into JavaScript: How much vs. how often?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, oop

I am building an OO website that shows one short story (out of thousands stored in my database) on the front page. Button clicks will display either the next (newer) or the previous (older) story. I have difficulty deciding whether I should

1) load all of these stories into a JavaScript array on document.ready (perhaps not the most maintainable solution as database grows)

or rather

2) query the database on each button click to store only the story that should be displayed in a JavaScript object

On a sidenote, I will most likely be building a search page, where all these stories can be filtered by different parameters. Assuming that I would go with solution no. 2, I should probably also choose to query the database on each such search query?

Comment: you can call ajax on click and get your result accordingly

Comment: my question is whether it is more efficient to do once or repeatedly

Comment: Or 3) load the first 10 stories up-front. When the user clicks "next", and lands on the 10th story, load 10 more stories in the background, so that they are ready if the user wants to continue. It is just text, so I would not worry too much about efficiency. Obviously, loading a new story from the server will incur a request/response, but then again, loading them all may be slow and require more memory (especially on mobile devices).